# Replace duplicate code with function parameter

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code which contains a lot of repetition..

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.action_crop -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap

            val bitmapCropped = BitmapHelper.cropBitmap(bitmap, capturedReceiptImageView.getDimensions())

            capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapCropped)
            capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

            bitmap.recycle()
        }
        R.id.action_rotate_left -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap

            val bitmapRotated = BitmapHelper.rotateBitmap(bitmap, -90.0f)

            capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapRotated)
            capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

            bitmap.recycle()
        }
        R.id.action_rotate_right -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap

            val bitmapRotated = BitmapHelper.rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90.0f)

            capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapRotated)
            capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

            bitmap.recycle()
        }
        R.id.action_increase_contrast -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap

            val bitmapChangedContrast = BitmapHelper.changeBitmapContrast(bitmap, 1.10f)

            capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapChangedContrast)
            capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

            bitmap.recycle()
        }
        R.id.action_decrease_contrast -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap

            val bitmapChangedContrast = BitmapHelper.changeBitmapContrast(bitmap, 0.90f)

            capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapChangedContrast)
            capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

            bitmap.recycle()
        }
        R.id.action_save -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap
            BitmapHelper.saveBitmap(bitmap, capturedReceiptUri)
        }
        else -> { return false }
    }

    return true
}
```

I want to a lot of this duplication with a function that takes another function an pass in the functions rotateBitmap changeBitmapContrast etc which should call this in BitmapHelper and return the bitmap

How can I change my code to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this question should belong to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun applyBitmapOperation(imageView: ImageView): ((Bitmap) -> Bitmap) -> Unit {
    val bitmap = imageView.bitmap
    return { function ->
        val resultBitmap = function(bitmap)
        capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap)
        capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

        bitmap.recycle()
    }
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    val apply = applyBitmapOperation(capturedReceiptImageView)
    when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.action_crop -> {
            apply { bitmap ->
                BitmapHelper.cropBitmap(bitmap, capturedReceiptImageView.getDimensions())
            }
        }
        R.id.action_rotate_left -> {
            apply { bitmap ->
                BitmapHelper.rotateBitmap(bitmap, -90.0f)
            }
        }
        R.id.action_rotate_right -> {
            apply { bitmap ->
                BitmapHelper.rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90.0f)
            }
        }
        R.id.action_increase_contrast -> {
           apply { bitmap ->
                BitmapHelper.changeBitmapContrast(bitmap, 1.10f)
            }
        }
        R.id.action_decrease_contrast -> {
            apply { bitmap ->
                BitmapHelper.changeBitmapContrast(bitmap, 0.90f)
            }
        }
        R.id.action_save -> {
            val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap
            BitmapHelper.saveBitmap(bitmap, capturedReceiptUri)
        }
        else -> { return false }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I prefer your way of doing it so accepting yours as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working with the following..

```
    private fun applyBitmapOperation(predicate: KFunction2<@ParameterName(name = "bitmap") Bitmap, @ParameterName(name = "changeAmount") Float, Bitmap>, changeAmount: Float) {
    val bitmap = capturedReceiptImageView.bitmap

    val bitmapChanged = predicate.invoke(bitmap, changeAmount)

    capturedReceiptImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapChanged)
    capturedReceiptImageView.invalidate()

    bitmap.recycle()
}
```

And call it like this..

```
applyBitmapOperation(::changeBitmapContrast, 1.10f)
```